# Can a pointer to a C++ enum's underlying type be turned into a pointer to the enum value?

Tags: c++, enums, language-lawyer, c++20, reinterpret-cast

Is there a legal way, according to the C++20 standard, to turn a pointer to an unscoped enumeration type's underlying type into a pointer to the enumeration type? In other words:

```cpp
enum Enum : int {
  FOO = 0,
  BAR = 1,
}

// How do I implement this without undefined behavior (and ideally without
// implementation-defined behavior)?
const Enum* ToEnum(const int* p);
```

I'm surprised to find that it's not [listed](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.reinterpret.cast) as a legal use of `reinterpret_cast`.

If you're interested in why I want this: in a templated API I'm trying to work around the fact that protocol buffers provide repeated enum fields as a `proto2::RepeatedField<int>`, i.e. an array of `int`s, despite the fact that there is a strongly-typed enum associated with the field. I would like to be able to turn this into a `std::span<Enum>` without needing to copy the values.

Comment: Could create a borrowed range that does a `static_cast` on dereference?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` will work fine. It's using the resulting pointer that will not work.

Comment: _I'm surprised to find that it's not listed as a legal use of `reinterpret_cast`._ https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.reinterpret.cast#7?

Comment: Thank you language lawyer tag inhabitants for your pedantry, which is exactly what I'm after. :-) Yes, what I mean is that I want to be able to obtain a pointer and then _actually be able to dereference it_.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not one of the very few exceptions to the **aliasing** rule ([basic.lval]/11): you can *construct* such a `std::span`, but attempting to use its elements (*e.g.*, `s.front()=FOO`) has undefined behavior.